# Adding values to specific DataTable cells

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid, datatable

I'm wondering if it's possible to add values to specific DataTable cells?

Suppose I have an existing dataTable and I add a new column, how would I go about adding to the new column's rows without overwriting the existing columns' rows?

As far as I'm aware, there isn't a method for adding to specific cells (unless I'm wrong).

```
  dt.Rows.Add(a, b, c, d)
```

where a, b, c and d are string values. So what if I just want to add to the d column?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If it were a completely new row that you wanted to only set one value, you would need to add the whole row and then set the individual value:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
dr[3].Value = "Some Value";
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
```

Otherwise, you can find the existing row and set the cell value

```
DataRow dr = dt.Rows[theRowNumber];
dr[3] = "New Value";
```

Comment: `dr[3] = "New Value";`  The ".Value" isn't needed.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
dt.Rows[RowNumber]["ColumnName"] = "Your value"
```

For example: if you want to add value 5 (number 5) to 1st row and column name "index" you would do this

```
dt.Rows[0]["index"] = 5;
```

I believe DataTable row starts with 0

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that but atleast you can update it. In order to edit an existing row in a DataTable, you need to locate the DataRow you want to edit, and then assign the updated values to the desired columns.

Example,

```
DataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(4).Item(0) = "Updated Company Name"
DataSet1.Tables(0).Rows(4).Item(1) = "Seattle"
```

**[SOURCE HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tat996zc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to add a new row and only put data in a certain column? Try the following:

```
var row = dataTable.NewRow();
row[myColumn].Value = "my new value";
dataTable.Add(row);
```

As it is a data *table*, though, there will always be data of some kind in every column. It just might be `DBNull.Value` instead of whatever data type you imagine it would be.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking for an updated correct syntax for this as I was, try the following:

```
Example:
dg.Rows[0].Cells[6].Value = "test";
```